# I want to swap values from a column to NA if there are NAs in other columns on the same row

Tags: r

i'm working on an assignment, the problem is that some rows have NA's in every columns except one, for some reasons linked to the assigment i have to transforms those values on that column to NA as well. I've never seen this manipulation in class so i don't know what to do. Need some help :)

I didn't try anything cause i have no idea what to try but i'll describe the problem as much as possible.

[image]

as you can see, there are NA's in all columns except the last one and i'd like the values in the last column to be NA as well.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you edit to provide more details, including reproducible code, sample data (in code, not images), and desired output?

Answer (score 0):

here is a dplyr solution, if I get you right:
First a reproducible example:

```
df <- data.frame(A= c("yes", NA_character_, NA_character_, "no"),
           B = c("yes", NA_character_, NA_character_, "yes"),
           C = c("no", NA_character_, NA_character_, "no"), 
          D = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_),
          E = c("yes", "yes", "yes", "yes"))
    
df <- df %>% mutate(E = case_when((is.na(A) & is.na(B) & is.na(C)) ~ NA_character_ , TRUE ~ E))
```

the mutate change column E. case_when checks if columns A, B and C are NA. If so, E is replaced with NA_character.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively with base r

```r
df$E <- ifelse(rowSums(is.na(df))>0,NA, 'yes')


     A    B    C    D  E
1  yes  yes   no <NA> NA
2 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> NA
3 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> NA
4   no  yes   no <NA> NA
```